# What does it mean by "the process starts out in state $i$"?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $\{X(t): t \geq 0\}$ be a continuous-time Markov chain. Let $T_{i}$ denote the holding time in state $i$. Then we have the following proposition:

[image]
[image]

Could you please explain what does it mean mathematically by "the process starts out in state $i$"? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it means $X(0) = i$. You are using time homogeniety because it does not matter at what time you hit $i$, so WLOG let time itself start running once you hit $i$ : which is the same as saying $X(0) = i$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Assume that our process is defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$. Do you mean $X_0 = i$ by $X_0 (\omega) = i$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$?

Comment: Correct, it is the constant random variable $i$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Let's not assume $X_0 = i$. I again arrive at $\left\{T_{i}>s\right\} \iff \{X(u)=i \text { for } 0 \leq u \leq s\}$. Could you please explain how we adjust in the general case $X_0 \neq i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convert @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг's comment as answer to close this question.

---

> I think it means $X(0) = i$. You are using time homogeniety because it does not matter at what time you hit $i$, so WLOG let time itself start running once you hit $i$ : which is the same as saying $X(0) = i$.